# Is it required to call ResolveUrl() before LoadControl()?

Tags: .net, asp.net, loadcontrol, resolveurl, resolveclienturl

Is it required to call `TemplateControl.ResolveUrl()` before passing it to `TemplateControl.LoadControl()`?

Which way is preferred?

```
LoadControl(ResolveUrl("~/MyControl.ascx"));
LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");
LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
```

or maybe `ResolveClientUrl()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not required.  I wouldn't even recommend doing the first method, since it's just redundant and adds complexity.  The tilde means it's relative to the application root already - `ResolveUrl` just changes it to be relative to the page or usercontrol you're calling it from.  Either way, it will still be loaded.

The second way would be preferred as a best practice to help guard against relative structural changes to your project.

Even better would be to make the path string a resource or at least a constant to get rid of magic strings and avoid surprises altogether.